# Material Design (materialize css) modal, IE issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, material-design, materialize

I'm using [Materialize CSS modals](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) which seem to have a problem on IE (even demo on their own site won't work on IE). I've tested modals using IE11 and while modals open fine, they don't seem to close properly. Opening a modal and then closing it will cause an overlay (?) issue? Modals work on Chrome and Firefox. Sidenav (also javascript overlaying content) however works fine on IE too.

I wonder if there was any way to work around this?

Disclaimer:
I'm just a humble designer, apologies for my javascript noobness.

Many thanks for everyone reading, commenting, helping with this matter.

Comment: If there was a way to work round it, then the materialize developers would already have done so.

Answer (score 1):

Use $('#id').modal()[0].M_Modal.options.close = true;

Comment: there is issue with this, scroll bar is hidden after close. I am still trying to get the solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this bug for older browsers like IE in Materialize v0.100.1.

This bug has been fixed in version **Materialize v0.100.2**

Fix:
**LINE 2120**: _this2.$overlay[0].parentNode.removeChild(_this2.$overlay[0]);